# Recommendation system with laravel Framework

Tags: laravel

I have downloaded a project from github for recommendation system in laravel but when I change the images ti fit my project the project save the old images. I tried also to delete them but it also shows the old images.
The Project uses json seed data file. (not from database)
Project link :https://github.com/oliverlundquist/laravel-recommender-system

Comment: At a glance it would seem all you need to do is change the `image` property in the `storage/data/products-data.json` file. Is this not the case? Make sure the json file isn't being cached by your browser.

Comment: I think that.How can I make my browser not to be cashing the images.I tried to find something in the project for cancel cashing.But I didn't find useful things.

Comment: I tried to make the disable cache from browser but it seems the same thing

Comment: How can I change this property to be useful?I can't understand the images fetching mechanism